# Dynamically Allocating 2D Arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, multidimensional-array

First of all, I'm no expert in C programming and I'm now reading some legacy C-code. There, I found the following function for initialize a 2D matrix:

```
long int **computeDistanceMatrix(void){
    long int i;
    long int j;
    long int ** matrix;
    matrix = malloc(sizeof(long int) * numberOfCities * numberOfCities +
        sizeof(long int *) * numberOfCities);

    if(matrix == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory, exit.");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfCities; i++){
        matrix[i] = (long int*) (matrix + numberOfCities) + i * numberOfCities;
        for (j = 0; j < numberOfCities; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = distanceFunction(i, j);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

I found the code a bit weird because I was expecting something [more similar to this](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html) that seems more clear to me. Anyway, I was wondering the following:

- That the line `malloc(sizeof(long int) * numberOfCities * numberOfCities +       sizeof(long int *) * numberOfCities)` means that they're allocating memory for data items and the pointers to each row?
- What does exactly mean `matrix[i] = (long int*) (matrix + numberOfCities) + i * numberOfCities`? I'm really not getting what they're trying to do.
- Is there a more straightforward way to do memory allocation for a 2D array in C, or that's the proper way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `sizeof (long int) = l`, `n` cities, and `sizeof (long int *) = p`, this piece of code tries to do pretty much the same thing as [the article you link to in your question](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html). Only, it tries to do it with one call to `malloc` instead of many.

The first `np` bytes allocated serves to hold the `n` pointers. Each of these pointers points to a chunk of `nl` long integers. The `long int` blocks are of course, all adjacent, with the first block itself being adjacent to the block of `n`, p-sized pointers, and starting at the address `matrix + np`.

The line:
`matrix[i] = (long int*) (matrix + numberOfCities) + i * numberOfCities`

.. sets up each of those `n` pointers to point to the correct place within the block. And hopefully, the following ASCII art makes that clear enough ;)

```
(addr = matrix +)  0    p    2p .. np   np+nl np+2nl

[matrix]-------->[ v    v    v  .. ^    ^     ^
                   |    |    |     |    |     |
                   |____|____|_____|    |     |
                        |____|__________|     |
                             |________________|
```

I do not know if this sort of 'optimization' (at the expense of reduced readability) brings advantages. Some might be:

1. It probably reduces the amount of book-keeping needed to be done by the `malloc` implementation. But there is also added cost in that we now calculate the pointer values ourselves.
2. The entire 2D array can be gotten rid of in one `free` call (of course, there is the problem that the programmer freeing the code should know that one `free` call is all he/she must make).
3. Might have advantages w.r.t. caching. The array is in one block, and spatial locality comes into play. On the other hand, multiple `malloc` calls might return blocks far away from each other.

Comment: Don't forget to read about VLAs in [Jens Gustedt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19759814/274261).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see people only have been proposing emulations of 2D-matrices so far.

Since C99, C has a concept of variable length arrays, VLA, that allows to allocate proper 2D matrices with dynamical bounds. Since usually these are too large for the stack you'd have to allocate them through `malloc`, something like this:

```
double (*A)[n] = malloc(sizeof(double[n][n]));
```

No complicated pointer to pointer scheme, necessary, just one single allocation of a contiguous object. You can then access elements of that matrix as simply as `A[i][j]` and the compiler is doing all the index calculations for you.

So whenever you may (you don't have legacy code that imposes pointer to pointer, you have a compiler that supports C99) you should use that. It is simpler, less error prone and more efficient.

Comment: In the last sentence you said, `more efficient`, computationally speaking, is this form more efficient? why?

Comment: @yeyo, multiple reasons: only one call to `malloc` (and `free`) instead of many, this is a contiguous allocation without holes, accessing elements is simple arithmetic without redirection and can be done directly by most mondern hardware. https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/dont-use-fake-matrices/

Comment: It make sense, totally. Thank you, I genuinely appreciate it. Your blog; wonderful!

Comment: @Jens Gustedt very interesting!, just to make sure i understand, would `double A[2][3][4]` be declared as `double (*A)[3][4] = malloc(sizeof(double[2][3][4]));`?

Answer (score 1):

`matrix[i] = (long int*) (matrix + numberOfCities) + i * numberOfCities;`

Like you said yourself - they are allocating memory for both data and pointers and the data is going to be sequential.  But allocating the data is not enough, since the pointers are not initialize (pointing to garbage) so now they have to set the pointers to actually point to the data.

It's important to understand that what they did is that first you have all the pointers and only then the data, something like that: [ptr1,ptr2,ptr3,data1[],data2[],data3[]]

so now lets look at the first pointer - he should point to the start of the array, so if `i=0` then we get `matrix[0] = (long int*)(matrix + numberOfCities);` which points right to beginning of the data section.

For `i=1` we get `matrix[0] = (long int*)(matrix + numberOfCities) numberOfCities;` which exactly "one block of numberOfCities" after the beginning of the data section.

Answer (score 1):

First `numberOfCities` items of `matrix` are `long int*`, and they point to the corresponding rows which allows to write `matrix[i][j]` to get to the element (i,j). The following bytes are treated as being `long int`.

The answers:

1) Yes.

2) `matrix+numberOfCities` is a pointer to the first data row, but it's still `long int**`. It is then converted to `long int*` and then it is moved further by `i*numberOfCities` elements (each of them is `long int`).

3) You can allocate the memory as a single array and perform 2D->1D index computations. Or you can allocate array of pointers and then allocate an array for each row. Or you can allocate array of pointers and then allocate array for all data, and then set the pointers to the corresponding items in the data array so that each pointer points to its row.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of creating a 2D array is:

```
long** create2DArray(int rows, int cols)
{
    // create an array of long* pointers
    long** ptr = (long**) malloc(sizeof(long*) * rows);

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        // allocate an array for each row
        ptr[i] = (long*)malloc(sizeof(long) * cols));
    }
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    long int** ptr = create2DArray();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way to allocate dynamically a 2D array

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int **array;
array = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
if(array == NULL)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //or return here
    }
for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
    array[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
    if(array[i] == NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //or return here
        }
    }
```

The main idea is to declare a pointer to a pointer of int .This is your matrix (array). Firstly, you dynamically allocate size equal of the first dimensions you want.Then you dynamically allocate another array of pointers of integers.

What you really have to understand is that there are no "dimensions" , when you dynamically allocate space in memory.They are just some random places.Having that in mind, you can allocate a N-D dimension array and go beyond from the 2-D limits.

Comment: This is not more "right" than the OP, it might be easier to read but it also have some downsides compared to the original (the data is not laid out in memory the same as in the OP).

Comment: but it is easier to understand

Comment: Torner you are right.I tried with difficulty understand the code posted.It seems fine now to me.Nevermind, i don't think that the use of OP ,is necessary here.You really do not get enough of these.Finally, you have to considered what is more beneficial for you as a programmer (save time or try to "put" better the memory ?) .I think that depends really on dev's choice.